# Calculate image sizing factor

Tags: graphics, scaling

How can I multiply a length e.g. `\textwidth` with two factors?
Other way to express what I want to do is, How can I apply more than one mathematical expression within `\includegraphics` command?

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \def\factor{0.15}
    \null\hfill
    \subfloat[]{
        \includegraphics[height=\factor\textheight]{imageA}
        \label{fig:image:B}
    }
    \hfill
    \subfloat[]{
        \includegraphics[height=0.5\factor\textheight]{imageB}                 <-------
        \label{fig:image:B}
    }
    \hfill\null
    \caption{capitiontext}
    \label{fig:images}
\end{figure}
```

What I have working is a defined factor as multiplicator. I now want to add another factor to this in some cases of the subfigures (I have a bunch of them sometimes).
I keep getting the error

> Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). }
>
> Package calc Error: `.' invalid at this point. }

Hopefully somebody has a nice little hint for me. Maybe I am doing something wrong by using a macro as factor...

Comment: You can use `0.5\dimexpr\factor\textheight`...

Comment: Alright, this does the trick. As I found out the documentation of this is in the [E-Tex Manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/etex/base/etex_man.pdf), paragraph 3.5 Expressions.
Thanks for the help.
@Werner Please post this as answer (though it's that short) so I can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Evaluate the one factor first using a dimension expression `\dimexpr`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\def\factor{0.15}
\includegraphics[height=\factor\textheight]{example-image}

\includegraphics[height=0.5\dimexpr\factor\textheight]{example-image}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a simpler approach:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newlength{\ftextheight}
\newcommand{\setfactor}[1]{%
  \setlength{\ftextheight}{#1\textheight}%
}

\begin{document}

\setfactor{0.15}

\includegraphics[height=\ftextheight]{example-image}

\includegraphics[height=0.5\ftextheight]{example-image}

\end{document}
```

The command `\setfactor` defines `\ftextheight` as the factor times `\textheight`, so you can later use this dimension. A subsequent `\setfactor` command will change the value of `\ftextheight` (usual scoping rules apply).

[image: 1]

Comment: Thanks @egreg for that answer. I though don't get why this would be a better solution. I don't have to define the factor within each figure you mean?